# fetching solr error message

Tags: php, solr

I am getting response of solr request as

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">400</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
        <str name="msg">
            Unexpected close tag </delete>; expected </query>. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,40]
        </str>
        <int name="code">400</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

i need to get the error message, but i dont understand how to access this.

Comment: What is the solr request that you are sending? From the error message it appears that you are attempting to execute a delete query and your delete statement syntax is incorrect.

Comment: my question is how to read error from the xml tag     <lst name="error">

Comment: You should be able to use XPATH - http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Answer (score 0):

For a full stack trace take a look in the output of the solr server or check the log files.

Comment: i need output as

"            Unexpected close tag </delete>; expected </query>. at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,40]"